# query user display_name failed in a custom mysql query foreach

Tags: wp-query, loop

I met some trouble. I tried to get user display_name in a custom mysql query foreach, but it failed. I have tried three method. `new WP_User`, `get_user_by` and `get_userdata`. but they only can get back the result `$user->display_name` which is ID=1 in table `wp_users`(admin). failed get any `$user->display_name` which ID=2(3,4...) in table `wp_users`. What should I do to solve this question? many thanks.

```
$results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM custom_table");// query connect from a custom database, not in database wp.
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($results)) {
global $wpdb;
$user = new WP_User($row['user_id']);
//$user = get_user_by('id',$row['user_id']);                
//$user = get_userdata($row['user_id']);
var_dump($user);
}
```

**edit**

Here is my full code. same code, If `SELECT * FROM test_table where id = 1` I could get the user display name `admin`, but if I try `SELECT * FROM test_table where id = 3` I could not get the display name, the back value is empty (I have checked the `wp_users` table, ID = 3 really has a member.)

```
header("Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8"); 
$mysql_hostname = "localhost";
$mysql_user = "root";
$mysql_password = "root";
$mysql_database = "test_db";
$db = mysql_connect($mysql_hostname, $mysql_user, $mysql_password)
or die('Error connection to database server: ' . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($mysql_database, $db)
or die('Error connection to database server: ' . mysql_error());
mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");
$results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM test_table where id = 3");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($results)) {
    //echo $row['id'];  I can get the $row['id'] value.
    $foo_db = new wpdb('root','root','wp','localhost'); 
    $foo_result = $foo_db->get_results("SELECT * FROM `wp_users` WHERE ID = '".addslashes($row['id'])."'",OBJECT);
    foreach($foo_result as $user){ 
        var_dump($user);
    }
}
```

BTW: test_table is very simple, just has 1 field, record the user ID. (ID:1 - ID:33)

Comment: You really need to look at the wpdb documentation. http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb

Comment: @Brian Fegter, so do you know how to do it? I have even tried `$user = $wpdb->get_row($wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM wp_users WHERE ID = '".addslashes($row['id'])."'"));` instead of `$user = new WP_User($row['user_id']);`, still failed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use all of the goodness of the wpdb object.

```
#Create a new WPDB object for your custom DB
$foo_db = new wpdb('username','password','database','localhost');
$query = ('SELECT * FROM custom_table');

#Use the get_results method - You can return OBJECT(default), OBJECT_K, ARRAY_A, ARRAY_N
$results = $foo_db->get_results($query, OBJECT);
foreach($results as $row){
    $user = new WP_User($row->user_id);
}
```

You can read more here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#SELECT_Generic_Results

To note, if you are selecting from the same server that uses the same credentials, try the following instead so as not to nest another identical connection:

```
global $wpdb;
$query = 'SELECT * FROM db_name.custom_table';
$results = $wpdb->get_results($query);
```

Hope this helps you!

Comment: I have tried your method, sitll failed, check my edit in question part. I have update a minium code for test. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

try it like this one:

```
$results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM custom_table");// all the stuff you did up until here
global $wpdb;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($results)) {

    $query = "SELECT display_name FROM wp_users WHERE ID = %d";
    $user_display_name = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare( $query, $row['user_id'] ) );
    echo $user_display_name . "<br />";

}
```

this should do it.

notice the prepare function used on the $wpdb object to ensure the safety of the query.